# Why don't I see more progress when sanding my stair treads?

Tags: stairs, sanding, hardwood

Doing some DIY around the house, any suggestions would greatly help.
I want to refinish my indoor steps and railing(sand and repaint)
When i am trying to sand the steps its very hard to sand it, although i am applying pressure i dont see it sanding (no dust/powder).Basically nothing is happening. Sanding paper i am using is Grit 80.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong or what is missing?
Thanks in advance.[image]

[image: Done]

Comment: Grit 80? Bud, you need 24 or 36 for the first pass. Then 60, then 80, then 120, and finish with 160 for an excellent finish.

Comment: Thanks man, newbie here, still learning :)

Comment: You picked a tough job for a newbie... :-)

Comment: Don't worry, we're **all** still learning. The only ones that are not learning are the ones which gave up :-)

Comment: Floors and stairs receive finishes which are meant to take abuse for decades so that's why 80 grit is doing practically nothing. I'm not sure what your expectations are but I see those stairs are quite damaged so the end result could be disheartening. You could save yourself a lot of disgruntlement if you decide to simply paint the stairs with a high quality paint designed for foot traffic. An oil-based or shellac-based primer would do well for adhesion to the existing polyurethane.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, those grits are appropriate for an entire floor with a drum or plate sander. You wouldn't use them with a hand sander. 60 is as coarse as I've ever wanted to use.

Comment: The "easy" way to clean up the damage would be remove the treads and use a planer/thicknesser machine or a jack plane to take off the varnish.

Answer (score 11):

A vibrating or oscillating sander isn't going to be aggressive enough for that job. It's really only suitable for light finish sanding. You need something that spins, or at least something with a random orbit (more movement).

80 grit is probably a good choice for working through the varnish on your steps but you need the moves only a different type of sander provides or you'll grow old waiting. Part of the problem is that varnish clogs paper grit quickly--it doesn't let go like clean sawdust does.

You might also consider chemically stripping the varnish to hurry the restoration process. Sanding through it can be a real chore.

All that said, if you have the option of temporarily removing your treads, that's what I'd be doing. You'll have a difficult time getting satisfactory results around the edges with them installed. You'll have visible lines from the existing varnish and stain, and you may have visible surface level variation as well. If you can gently pop them out, pull the nails out the back side, and sand or strip fully in a workshop area, that's the ticket.

Comment: While I agree 100% with removing the treads and refinishing on the bench, those look like they're cased in, so removal isn't quite as easy as "pop the nails & pull". _If_ there's adequate access to the underside of the staircase, the OP may be able to figure out exactly how the treads were installed and be able to pull them out from there. May not be a 1st DIY level project, though.

Comment: Yeah, the skirt may need to be removed as well. It's not clear whether they could be lifted out from the left. .

Comment: @jayroy Stripping the varnish is no cake-walk either. Some of the products recommend letting it sit for 8 hours or more so those stairs will be completely inaccessible in the meantime. I tried letting one sit for 48 hours when I was refinishing my floors and the results were disappointing. Big box stores generally won't sell the good stuff that professionals use as it can be quite noxious. Even if you succeed you will likely have to do some sanding to remove all of the old color.

Comment: I've had success with *heat* stripping varnish, on smaller surfaces like door trims.

Comment: @GlenYates a belt sander could work on removed treads, but a) they cut material _really_ fast, which takes lots of practice to keep even across an entire piece, and b) anything in-place like this would be really hard to get right as a belt sander can't reach 3 of the edges. You'd have almost as much trouble matching the edges with another technique as using that alternative for the entire piece.